# Parsing nested array Json to Java, from DistanceMatrix Google Api with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, google-distancematrix-api

I need to parsing Json in Java object and save the fields: destination_addresses, origin_addresses and duration. I can not get the values of "duration". This is the json which I have to parse:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Blocco Palma Primo, 95121 Fattoria Sole Delfino CT, Italia" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "Unnamed Road, 95121 Catania CT, Italia",
      "Blocco Palma Primo, 95121 Fattoria Sole Delfino CT, Italia",
      "Contrada Torre Allegra, 95121 Catania CT, Italia",
      "Contrada Pantano d'Arci, Catania CT, Italia",
      "Unnamed Road, 95121 Catania CT, Italia",
      "Via Cassia, 95121 Catania CT, Italia",
      "Contrada Pantano d'Arci, Catania CT, Italia",
      "Contrada Pantano d'Arci, Catania CT, Italia",
      "Contrada Pantano d'Arci, Catania CT, Italia",
      "Contrada Pantano d'Arci, Catania CT, Italia"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "2,0 km",
                  "value" : 2037
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "4 min",
                  "value" : 266
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 m",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 min",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "3,8 km",
                  "value" : 3768
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "7 min",
                  "value" : 400
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "5,3 km",
                  "value" : 5304
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 min",
                  "value" : 374
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "8,2 km",
                  "value" : 8239
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "13 min",
                  "value" : 785
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "11,5 km",
                  "value" : 11486
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "15 min",
                  "value" : 901
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "12,2 km",
                  "value" : 12226
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "18 min",
                  "value" : 1099
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "12,2 km",
                  "value" : 12226
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "18 min",
                  "value" : 1099
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "12,2 km",
                  "value" : 12226
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "18 min",
                  "value" : 1099
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "12,2 km",
                  "value" : 12226
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "18 min",
                  "value" : 1099
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

And this is what I tried in Java, to get the fields that I need:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
        SRD sr = new Gson().fromJson(reader, SRD.class);
        
        System.out.println("destination: " + sr.destination_addresses.get(0));
        System.out.println("origins: " + sr.origin_addresses.get(2));
        System.out.println(sr.rows.get(2).elements.get(0).toString());
        
         
        
    }
```

With these classes:

```
private class SRD {
        List<String> destination_addresses;
        List<String> origin_addresses;
        List<elements> rows;
        
    }
    
    
    private class elements {
        List<duration> elements;
    
    }
    
    private class duration {
        String text;
        int value;

        
        public String toString() {
            return "duration{" + "text=" + text + ", value=" + value + '}';
        }
        
        
    }
```

Executing this code I get the following output:

> destination: Blocco Palma Primo, 95121 Fattoria Sole Delfino CT, Italy
>
> origins: Contrada Torre Allegra, 95121 Catania CT, Italy
>
> duration{text=null, value=0}

Obviously, I can successfully do the parsing of fields destination_addresses and origin_addresses, but not the duration, of which gives me values 0 and null. Where am I wrong? How can I solve this problem and get the correct values (text and value) of duration? Thank for your help.

Comment: The issue is that "element" is some object with a field duration (being some object text/value) not a list of duration. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ might help you

Comment: If I replace the content of my class "elements" with 'duration duration;' and the println in the main with 'System.out.println(sr.rows.get(2).duration.toString());' , the execution fails with error: _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at proveJson.SingleRouteParse.main(SingleRouteParse.java:35)_. I write this println following the tips of Netbeans.

Comment: Before I have used a list because in json, elements is followed by square brackets [

Comment: I didn't say anything about element**s**, element**s** is a list of element and an element is a type with a field "duration". Note that I gave you a tool to generate the classes.. So go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ - choose "source type" JSON - copy paste your json - choose "Annotation style" Gson, check the option you want and click generate, then use the generated classes

Comment: Thak you, I have seen the tool, I have use it and it help me to understand how to do the classes, but the program does not work the same.

Comment: Feel free to open a new question if needed for the "does not work the same"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, In java class names should start with uppercase.

If it is problem to access objects just define `getter` methods.

I didn't make seperate classes of duration and distance objects because of that they are both have same type and name properties.

```
private class SRD {
    List<String> destination_addresses;
    List<String> origin_addresses;
    List<Row> rows;

}

private class Row{
    List<Element> elements;

}


private class Element {
    General duration;
    General distance;
    String status; 

}

private class General {
    String text;
    int value;


    public String toString() {
        return "duration{" + "text=" + text + ", value=" + value + '}';
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved my problem. I modified classes in a manner similar to how you made about you, but did not work. Now I will try to understand why, but in the meantime I solved thanks to you.

Comment: what was the problem by the way?

Comment: It was the first time I had to parse json and probably I did not understand the mechanism, I did some changes before finding the solution and also called evil classes in println. In the end, thanks to your help, I managed to get it right and understand how to reason. Thanks again.